# Story of a man who fell into an underground city and emerged into the middle of the Spanish Civil War

Tags: story-identification

In school pre 1970 I read a story of a man who fell down a gyre to an underground city. It was run on electricity. He emerged into the middle of the Spanish civil war after climbing his way out.

Comment: Did he start out later than the Civil War, inputting time travel?

Comment: Do you remember if it was in a magazine or an anthology?

Comment: I recall it was a book from the school library not a magazine. Possibly anthology. There were suspended electric trams or trains. I think he did not time travel. He was hiding out observing things before being apprehended.